# Ignore certificate errors in Internet Explorer 11 with Katalon Studio

Tags: internet-explorer, katalon-studio, selenium-iedriver

SSL cert is invalid, so I got error message when test case is executed, manual intervention is needed to continue. I tried to ignore errors with use of `DesiredCapabilities`:

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities()
capabilities.setCapability(ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
```

Not sure, how to initialize IEDriver in Katalon Studio test case to put these.